# C Socket/Polling incorrectly returning POLLOUT event?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, polling

I'm trying to write a Port open test by using sockets and for some reason this is reporting "port open" for invalid IP addresses. I'm currently plugged into an access point that's not connected to the internet so this is incorrectly reporting port open for external IP addresses.

First I set up the socket and since this is nonblocking mode it's usually still in progress by the first `if` statement. Then I am polling the socket. However, for a socket on an external IP, I'm getting the POLLOUT event even though that doesn't seem possible...

**What am I missing? Why does the poll received events contain POLLOUT?** I've tried resetting the `pollfd` struct before calling poll again but that didn't change the result.

```
result = connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

if(result == 0) //woohoo! success
{
    //SUCCESS!
    return true;
}
else if (result < 0 && errno != EINPROGRESS) //real error
{
    //FAIL
    return false;
}

// poll the socket until it connects
struct pollfd fds[1];
fds[0].fd = sd;
fds[0].events = POLLOUT | POLLRDHUP | POLLERR | POLLNVAL;
fds[0].revents = 0;

while (1)
{
    result = poll(fds, 1, 1);

    if (result < 1)
    {
        //Poll failed, mark as FAIL
    }
    else
    {
        // see which event occurred
        if (fds[0].revents & POLLOUT || fds[0].revents & POLLRDHUP)
        {
           //SUCCESS
        }
        else if (fds[0].revents & POLLERR || fds[0].revents & POLLNVAL)
        {
            //FAIL
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not crazy about the code structure and error checking here. If the connect succeeds or doesn't cause EINPROGRESS you shouldn't enter the select loop at all; and `poll()` doesn't cause EINPROGRESS. You need to clean this up and try again. You should also check SO_ERROR on the socket FD when you get the EPOLLOUT.

Comment: @EJP you're right. Deleted my answer and my apologies for the argue. I've performed further reading and experiments and concluded that my example was flawed. Anyway, thank you, learned something today!

Comment: @EJP see my edit. I've cleaned up the error checking and now I check SO_ERROR after EPOLLOUT

Comment: @threadp Thank you. Just to note for future readers that `connect()` does not return a file descriptor.

Comment: @EJP yes i noticed that also in the man-page. Got confused with `socket()` return value. Thanks

Comment: @kburbach It is still not clear that you aren't entering the loop if the connect succeeded. What is the invalid IP address you're connecting to? And are you sure the connect didn't succeed? Does a sequence of sends really fail (you need quite a few for buffering reasons)?

Comment: @EJP, whoops forgot to copy over the `return`. The IP addresses that I'm using are 172.217.0.68, 23.235.47.73, 153.104.63.227

Comment: @EJP your comment about checking SO_ERROR was the solution, so if you make that an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @kburbach am I misunderstanding or does your question now also contain the solution? You shouldn't do that. Leave it as it was so that people can understand what you were asking, or delete the question if you feel it is not helpful to others.

Comment: @davmac you were correct, I edited the question as I was adding in new ideas/comments. I've removed the actual solution from the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to check SO_ERROR after receiving the POLLOUT event - POLLOUT by itself does not indicate success.

```
//now read the error code of the socket
int errorCode;
uint len = sizeof(errorCode);
result = getsockopt(fds[0].fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR,
               &errorCode, &len);
```